# Removing default page margin on Squarespace

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, squarespace

I'm working on the following Squarespace site:

https://www.naomicambridge.squarespace.com

At the bottom of the home page are two testimonials with the same background colour as the footer. I've noticed that when I go to fullscreen on my browser the area with the testimonials has a margin round the edge where as the footer goes all the way to the edge of the page and I'd like the testimonials to match up with the footer.

I've added the following code:

```
div.sqs-block.quote-block.sqs-block-quote {
margin: -30px !important;
}
```

However this only seems to remove the margin from the left side and shifts everything slightly over to the left.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `margin` from `.Index-page-content` class and set `max-width` to `none`

```
.tweak-site-width-option-full-background .Index-page .Index-page-content  {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
}
```